# Batch File Script to Copy Files (Input lines from a Text File) from one Folder to Another

Tags: batch-file, copy, text-files

I have a text file EXAMPLE (as given below) which has the names of different files present in a folder.

> Filename1
>   Filename2
>   Filename3
>   .........

Now, I have to use this text file as the input to copy the files in D:\  drive (filenames are taken from text file) to another folder. The Batch file I used is given below.

```
@Echo Off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set n= 0
Set _InTextFile=D:\EXAMPLE.txt

For /F "tokens=*" %%I IN (%_InTextFile%) DO (

Set /a n+=1

Set _var!n!=%%I

set VAR=init

for /f %%a in ('dir /b D:\%%I.asc') do set VAR=exists

if %VAR%==exists

xcopy * D:\New folder

)

Set _

EndLocal

cmd /k
```

Unfortunately, this Batch script is not working as I expected. It is not copying the specific files to the new folder location. Also, it is getting printed as

> Invalid number of parameters.

Please try to help me to identify the exact problem in my Batch Script. How can I modify this script in order to copy only these specific files (as given in EXAMPLE text file) in the D:\ drive to the D:\New folder ?

Thank You in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve this by making the modification in my code as given below.

`set destinationfolder=D:\New folder`

`FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (E:\EXAMPLE.txt) DO XCOPY /I /S /Y "%%a" "%destinationfolder%\%%~nxa"`

This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the usage of the For.exe command. You can type For/? in a command-line to see the three ways to use it. The way your using it is to get attributes about the file and not for the data in the file.

```
REM Im trying to get FileSize or some other info about the file itself.
For /F "tokens=*" %%I IN (%_InTextFile%) DO ...

REM Should be this to process the file line by line.
For /F "UseBackQ tokens=*" %%I IN (%_InTextFile%) DO ...
```

2. Make the whole script "safer" by making the Dir.exe command more 
   explicit\specific. Make it Dir/A-D/B to not even list folders.
3. if %VAR%==exists needs to be !Var! for dynamic behavior.

4  The XCopy command is not using deriving any benefit from being in a procedure. The way its written write now is also dangerous and could potentially move files you dont want to move.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions. Actually, I tried to first get the attributes about the file, print it and then only I made a xcopy statement for copying the specific files. I am able to solve this problem easily just by modifying my for loop as I have explained in my answer below. Thank You for your suggestions, valuable time and consideration.